# Yii sorting gridview using Field

Tags: php, database, yii2

Can sort 2 arrays at a time, we need to sort array 1 and then we need to sort second one

```
 $array_ids = [5,7,3,9,2,8,1] //simple array
    $array_id2 = [78999, 89855,,...]//second array

    $modelsObj = Model::find()
            ->where(['id' => $array_ids]) // find only needed id's
            ->limit(5) //add limit if you need
            ->orderBy([new \yii\db\Expression('FIELD(id, '. implode(',', $array_ids) . ')')]) // sorting them as in array
            ->all();
```

Can we sort these two arrays ?

Comment: Are you asking about sorting the arrays themselves or _sorting_, as in _ordering_ the models based on the order of the IDs?

Comment: $dataProvider->query->orderBy([
            new \yii\db\Expression('FIELD (status, 0, invoice_status, 17,16,0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,status,4,5,7)')
        ]);

Comment: #Raul Sauco If you observe above one you can come to know what i want actually, 2 columns i need to sort based on the column values @Raul Sauco